# How to create a new path by replacing only a folder name of the path?

Tags: c#

I tried replacing it by the code below, but I get an error, "unrecognized escape sequence".

```
string originalPath = @"C:\project\temp\code";
string newPath = "";

newPath = originalPath.Replace("C:\project\temp", "C:\project\files");
```

Comment: try doubling up your backslashes C:\\project\\temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a String Declaration, if you use @ Symbol then String will be taken intact, in fact you don't need to bother about the escape sequences.

you have created OriginalPath variable with @ symbol so it will be taken as :

**originalPath = "C:\project\temp\code";**

Hence following both statements are valid:

```
1.string originalPath = @"C:\project\temp\code";
2.string originalPath = "C:\\project\\temp\\code";
```

Hence While Replacing the string you could use either of the way asbelow:

**Solution 1:**
`newPath = originalPath.Replace("C:\\project\\temp","C:\\project\\files");`

**Solution 2:**

`newPath = originalPath.Replace(@"C:\project\temp", @"C:\project\files");`

Answer (score 1):

Every string literal with backslashes needs either doubled baskslashes, or the @ symbol for a quoted string.

The 'unrecognized escape sequence' is "\p".

Try this:

```cs
newPath = originalPath.Replace(@"C:\project\temp", @"C:\project\files");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use double '/' ,because  first string is '@' and second isn't .

If it doesn't work I would suggest to find the instance of the temp using string.contains and Put \n there afterwards append the string with files .

If it doesn't work the try to use regex .